# I have just started to use nats with my NestJs Microservices, after npm i nats and recompiling my app I receive this error "stream.on"

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nats.io

This is the error in my cmd window after trying to run a npm start

```
C:\Users\Desktop\app\ms-users\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\server\server-nats.js:85
        stream.on(constants_1.ERROR_EVENT, (err) => this.logger.error(err));
               ^

TypeError: stream.on is not a function
    at ServerNats.handleError (C:\Users\Desktop\app\ms-users\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\server\server-nats.js:85:16)
    at ServerNats.listen (C:\Users\Desktop\app\ms-users\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\server\server-nats.js:22:14)
    at C:\Users\Desktop\app\ms-users\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\nest-microservice.js:86:51
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NestMicroservice.listenAsync (C:\Users\Deskto\app\ms-users\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\nest-microservice.js:86:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
```